# updated nexus from 2.6.2 to 2.11.1 fail

Tags: maven, nexus, sonatype

I'm trying to update nexus from  2.6.2 to 2.11.1 but I see errors in logs related to p2 plugin(it seems that in newer version that functionality is in the box). What should I do ?

Comment: here is my log http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=P7wkQ60G

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, p2 plugins should be updated to:

nexus-p2-bridge-plugin-2.11.1-01
nexus-p2-repository-plugin-2.11.1-01

Comment: The plugins should always be in sync with the version of Nexus. See more details at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/p2-sect-intro.html